# Integration of MNE Python in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, mne-python

Does anybody knows how to integrate mne python in google cloud.
We are basically using basic MEG analysis using data in Python and we want to import data onto Google Cloud and use the open source library MNE Python.

Have Tried of using sudo apt install mne-python in shell.

Answer (score 0):

Does mne-docker serve your purpose? Surely, it will require some changes to handle your file imports, but that might be a good starting point.

https://github.com/mne-tools/mne-docker

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).